# How do you pronounce letters generated with \Bbb and \mathbb?

Tags: bold, letters, italic, accessibility, pronunciation

I'm writing LaTeX to speech software.

In LaTeX, I pronounce **`R`** as "Boldface Ar".

How should I pronounce `$$\Bbb R$$`?

Comment: "The real numbers" usually. (but in an automated context if you have no clue to meaning, "double struck R" or "blackboard bold R" would be OK

Comment: If the purpose is to help read and write LaTeX code, then it would make more sense to actually read out the markup. If the software is intended as a format (like `pdflatex` or `xelatex`), then you might want to consider [accsupp](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) (or [glossaries-accsupp](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-accsupp)) so the author can provide the appropriate pronunciation.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot From the research papers I have read, it is much more difficult for visually impaired people to interpret latex through code alone.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'll add an answer that uses `accsupp` as I think that's the best approach to this problem.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot You should have told me 6 months ago when I started the project :P I'll have to see what it renders out. Mine is fairly unique in its approach, using sound effects and different voices to help articulate the formula.

Comment: I think your project is a good idea. There are some other resources listed at [PDF accessibility and PDF standards](http://tug.org/twg/accessibility/) on the TUG site.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Ah that is interesting; never came across that one. My main reference I have been using was Larry's Speakeasy: http://web.efzg.hr/dok/MAT/vkojic/Larrys_speakeasy.pdf  -- My interpreter is basically done, its just that I have to manually add functions that I had not already included, and determine how they should be interpreted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

BBB stands for [blackboard bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold), but "double struck" is also used [(e.g. ℝ)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211d/index.htm).  However how *it should be pronounced* is another matter -- between reading out the markup ("[dollar dollar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) backlash B B B space R") and the meaning of the symbol ("set of real numbers" is a big gap.

Comment: This answer implies it, but to state it explicitly: presumably there are domains and fields in which ℝ *doesn’t* mean “set of real numbers,” which is going to be a big problem for this project.

Comment: @KRyan - What do you base your presumption on?

Comment: @Mico Just because there is just about no symbol in the world not redefined by *someone* for *some purpose*. I can’t find any other usages of ℝ itself in a cursory search, but the point remains even if it applies to other characters.

Comment: @KRyan - If some author chooses to use `\mathbb{N}` and `\mathbb{R}` for anything *but* the sets of positive integers and real numbers, respectively, I'd fully expect this unusual form of notation to be flagged carefully and prominently by the author. If the author were to fail to do so, he/she would almost surely confuse the heck out of every single reader -- not just sight-impaired readers.

Comment: @Mico I share your opinion but as a mere physicist wouldn't want to assume *anything* about mathematicians' notation let alone what happens to it when other people use it.

Comment: @Mico And if that author did so, how would this software know it? This is about text-to-speech, not a program that can actually read and understand. If the author had already indicated the way the symbol should be read (e.g. `accsupp`), this program wouldn't be necessary in the first place, but I consider it entirely believable that someone would neglect to do so even while carefully explaining their notation in text.

Comment: @KRyan so we end up with a situation where if the author provides semantic assistive support everyone's happy. But if they don't we fall back on describing the markup using real words - probably the best we can hope for. The goal then should presumably be to make it concise, unambiguous, and as universal as possible

Comment: @ChrisH Right, hence the large gap between “dollar dollar backslash B B B space R” and “set of real numbers”—choosing where to fall on that continuum for each symbol is going to be tricky. “Blackboard bold R” or “Double-struck R” are probably better choices than “the set of real numbers” since even though the latter is more useful in almost-all situations, in that one weird corner-case it will be *wrong*.

Comment: @KRyan I agree. The edge cases aren't very likely for this, but the next question could well be about `\mathcal H` for which we couldn't assume a meaning.

Comment: ...or, closer to the OPs situation, `\mathbb{P}`, which I have seen being used both as generic notation for probability measure functions and the set of primes.

Answer (score 6):

When I first read your question, I wasn't quite sure which of the following applied to your tool:

1. The tool is for visually impaired users writing LaTeX code.
2. The tool is for visually impaired users who have been sent a LaTeX document because the PDF generated by `pdflatex` doesn't read correctly when used with a PDF to Speech tool.
3. The tool is for document authors who want to create an accessible version of their document for visually impaired users in much the same way as document authors might want to create both a PDF and HTML version of their document for the convenience of their readers.

I'm guessing from your comments that it's more likely case 2 or 3.

In the first case, the user really needs to know the markup. Trying to interpret the LaTeX code in this instance is like trying to create an audio version of lyx that hides the commands. I'm not sure how well that would work for visually impaired users.

In the second case, there's no reason to suppose that the user who has been sent the LaTeX code actually knows much about LaTeX, so reading out the commands is more likely to confuse them. In this instance, I think the symbols should simply be pronounced by their name rather than what they represent. Others have already mentioned Unicode. Given its ubiquity, I think it's best to use the Unicode description. This helps with standardisation.

If the listener understands the subject matter, they'll know what the symbol represents, especially if the topic is at an advanced level.

Now suppose the document is an introductory text about set theory that has something like:

> The set of real numbers (denoted ℝ) …

This won't make any sense if it's read as

> The set of real numbers (denoted the set of real numbers) …

The listener needs to know what that symbol is in case they encounter it in another document with another text to speech system that doesn't try interpreting it.

It's far less confusing to hear the symbol pronounced by its Unicode description that it is to hear an incorrect phrase caused by a misinterpretation of the symbol by an automated system that can't recognise the context.

For example, suppose the tool tries to be clever and reads `\$1` out as "one dollar", which is the way $1 is usually read by a sighted reader if it's in a currency context, but perhaps the document is actually an introductory guide to regular expressions and it's referring to the first matched group. The tool has now misinformed the listener.

The third case is the best use of your tool. The document author is going out of their way to provide an accessible version. If I'm writing a document that needs to be converted to multiple formats, I expect to write additional code that I wouldn't need if I was simply creating a PDF (except perhaps for trivial documents). As long as your tool recognises the `accsupp` package, the document author can provide the most appropriate pronunciation.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\begin{document}

\[
\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={set of real numbers}}
\mathbb{R}
\EndAccSupp{}
\]

\end{document}
```

This provides the text to read out when encountering that symbol. If you want to use the symbol a lot, then you might find it easier to use `glossaries-accsupp`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{glossaries-accsupp}

\newglossaryentry{R}{name={$\mathbb{R}$},
 text={\mathbb{R}},
 description={},
 access={set of real numbers}}

\begin{document}

\[ \gls{R} \]

\end{document}
```

This internally uses `\BeginAccSupp` but it's less cumbersome.

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{glossaries-accsupp}

\newglossaryentry{R}{name={$\mathbb{R}$},
 text={\mathbb{R}},
 description={},
 access={set of real numbers},
 firstaccess={set of real numbers (double-struck capital R)}
}


\begin{document}
$\gls{R}$

\[ \gls{R} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is both obvious and irrelevant. Of course document authors *should* provide accessibility support. That does a blind person absolutely no good when presented with a document that doesn’t, which is the point of the project and this question.

Comment: @KRyan I added this answer following on from the comments to the question since it's related and there's not enough room in the comments to elaborate.

Comment: Well, all right; that’s kind of an abuse of the SE format, and coming here from HNQs I was confused by it. As someone not from here, I would comment that I think that’s a *bad idea* and it would have been better to produce a self-answered Q&A to link to from comments. This information *is* useful, just not *here*, where it will be hard to find for the next person.

Comment: @KRyan - What does HNQ mean?

Comment: @Mico Hot Network Question. As in, the list of questions from other Stack Exchange sites that you see on the right.

Comment: @KRyan ... if you're reading on a big screen.  There are plenty of mobile users who don't get the sidebar

Comment: @ChrisH OK, sure. Forgot they didn't show on the mobile version or app.

Answer (score 0):

When i was a math student all these double struck letters were called "Japanese", because they were strange and "nobody in this class is knowing japanese 'letters'". Moreover this is an unambigious naming.